# Manual data normalization in python

Tags: python

I need to standardize a numpy ndarray in a way so that each value has the variance 1 and the mean is 0. I am however not allowed to use any kind of library etc. and have to do it manually. The code below is what I came up with, which gets the correct mean but the variance is wrong. I only manage to get the correct variance for the whole array but not for the single values.

EDIT: I found out, that the problem is caused, because some of the values are greater than 1, if the original value was a large number I am however unsure how to solve this...

```
def standardize_data(data):
  mean = np.mean(data)
  std = np.std(data)
  standardized_point = (data - mean)/std       
  return standardized_point
```

Comment: This is called *normalization*, which might help you with internet searches.

Comment: Hi thanks! I know that but i just don’t seem to manage to fix this problem

Comment: having values over 1 is normal and even expected after normalization. Why is it a problem?

Comment: > I only manage to get the correct variance for the whole array but not for the single values.
Variance is a metric for whole values, not for a single value.

Comment: I found out that I need to get the mean and the std of the different arrays inside the ndarray to get a variance that equals 1 over the single arrays. Not quite sure how to achieve that tho

Comment: You mean you want to normalize each row individually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function works fine for standardizing a one-dimensional array. So to standardize a two-dimensional array row-wise, you can simply apply your function to each row:

```py
def standardize_1d(data):
    mean = np.mean(data)
    std = np.std(data)
    return (data - mean) / std       

def standardize_2d(arr):
    return np.array([standardize_1d(row) for row in arr])
```

Comment: Hi, first of all thanks for the answer. However im not sure if im applying your function in a wrong way. Im entering `x = standardize_2d(xs_train)
np.var(x, axis = 0)` as the coding, with xs_train as the dataset. This should, according to the task I got, give me an array only containing ~1 for each value, which is not the case. What am I missing?

Comment: Just had to transpose it thanks so much!!

Comment: Iterating over a numpy array is usually a bad idea. In this case, `np.mean()` and `.std()` both take an `axis` argument that allows you to apply these functions rowwise or colwise.